# str_replace() has a search limit?

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a templating system for a current project. I use str_replace() to replace tokens within HTML documents with dynamic data.

For example, {%TEAM_NAME%} would be replaced with a name of a team taken from a table dependent on certain factors.

In one case the number of tokens (or string length of the search parameter) seems to have become so long it no longer replaces.

Here are snippets to show what I'm referring to:

```
$tokens = array('{%T_ID%}','{%NAV_BAR%}','{%TEAM_NAMES%}','{%CLUB_NAME%}','{%TEAM_NAME%}','{%STATE%}', '{%AGE_GROUP%}','{%LEVEL%}','{%CONTACT_NAME%}','{%CONTACT_ADDRESS%}','{%CONTACT_CITY%}','{%CONTACT_ZIP%}','{%CONTACT_EMAIL%}','{%CONTACT_PHONE_NUM%}','{%COACH_NAME%}','{%COACH_EMAIL%}','{%COACH_PHONE_NUM%}','{%SECRET_Q%}','{%SECRET_A%}','{%SO_CAL_ID%}','{%STATE_ID%}','{%NUM_PLAYERS%}','{%NOTES%}','{%SCORE_W%}','{%SCORE_L%}','{%SCORE_T%}','{%SCORE_GF%}','{%SCORE_GA%}','{%SCORE_GD%}','{%SCORE_POINTS%}');

    $replace = array(
        $tId => null,
        $navBar->Parse() => null,
        $teamNameOptions => null,
        _CLUB_NAME_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _TEAM_NAME_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _STATE_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        $ageOptions => null,
        $levelOptions => null,
        _CONTACT_NAME_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _CONTACT_ADDRESS_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _CITY_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _ZIP_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _CONTACT_EMAIL_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _CONTACT_PHONE_NUM_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _COACH_NAME_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _COACH_EMAIL_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _COACH_PHONE_NUM_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _SECRET_Q_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _SECRET_A_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _SO_CAL_ID_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _STATE_ID_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _NUM_PLAYERS_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _NOTES_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _SCORE_W_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _SCORE_L_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _SCORE_T_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _SCORE_GF_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _SCORE_GA_ => _TEAM_TABLE_,
        _SCORE_POINTS_ => _TEAM_TABLE_
    );
```

Doing some extensive white-box testing the values are all there, however the very last token and replacement {%SCORE_POINTS%} is not being replaced with a number as a should be, rather null.

This:

```
<input type="text" name="fScorePoints" value="{%SCORE_POINTS%}">
```

Should become:

```
<input type="text" name="fScorePoints" value="5">
```

But actually becomes:

```
<input type="text" name="fScorePoints" value="">
```

I tested further by adding another token and replacement and that too is not properly replaced, leading me to assume there is some form of character limit?

I can confirm all other tokens and replacements work perfectly fine, just not this last one.

What's going on?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: You have 30 tokens and only 29 to replace. This is why the last is always blank.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to update the removal of {%SCORE_GD%} thanks.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, please post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @Lee you have destroyed this as a resource for other in the future with your edit - very selfish.

Comment: @lee You should not delete the question when a solution is found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation for str_replace()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

> If search and replace are arrays, then str_replace() takes a value
>   from each array and uses them to search and replace on subject. If
>   replace has fewer values than search, then an empty string is used for
>   the rest of replacement values.

As the commenter pointed out, you have 1 less replacement value than you have subjects.

Comment: Thanks for that. A case of word blindness!

Comment: Happens to all of us! :)

Answer (score 2):

While your question has been answered by others, I would point out that there is a more scalable way to do what you're doing. By using a callback function, you can replace all things of the syntax

```
{%VARIABLE_NAME%}
```

With items of an array $array['VARIABLE_NAME'];

I could just copy it out, but I've had a function on my website for a while.

http://www.bumcheekcity.com/pages/112-php-code

It should be of use to you or other people with your problem of wanting to replace strings like this.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing '{%SCORE_GD%}' in your replace is this causing the issue?

*Edit*  Apparently forgetting to refresh the page before posting is a bad thing i was late on this one!